# Php Mysqli: Looping 18,000 records and got fatal error: Maximum execution time even after 5minutes

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
    $par1='0';

    $db -> autocommit(FALSE); // start transaction

    $stmtInv = $db->prepare("SELECT invoice,date,route,customer FROM test WHERE type = ? GROUP BY invoice");
    $par1="Sales Receipt";
    $stmtInv -> bind_param('s',$par1);
    $stmtInv -> execute();
    $stmtInv -> bind_result($invoice,$date,$route,$customer);

    // loop 9,000 records
    while($stmtInv -> fetch()){ 
         //update statements
    }

    $stmtInv -> free_result();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT code, pid FROM test");
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> store_result();
    $stmt -> bind_result($code,$id);

    // loop 9,000 records
    while($stmt -> fetch()){
        $stmtUpdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE test SET code = ? WHERE code = ?");
        $par1="test";$par2="test";
        $stmtUpdate -> bind_param("ss",$par1,$par2);
        $stmtUpdate -> execute();

        $stmtId = $db->prepare("UPDATE test t INNER JOIN products p ON (t.code = p.Pr_code) SET t.pid = p.Pr_id");
        $stmtId -> execute();
    }

    $stmt -> free_result();

    $db -> autocommit(TRUE);
?>
```

I'm renaming data from column 'code' with 9,000 records each loop. I first tried display data from the two loop and it was successful. But when I add update statement from each loop, I get a maximum execution time even after adjusting execution time to 300 seconds. Am I writing my sql correctly?

Comment: use `sql` call `pagination` system , you got this because the server memory cannot handle all your request , you need to use `pagination`

Comment: I didn't try to figure out the whole code, but looping over data like this in PHP (or any other language)is generally bad practice. By the looks of this, you should be able to create a single query for this. This will NEVER perform satisfactory.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle what is the proper way to loop over data? can you give a reference?

Comment: That would be a JOIN for instance. Many web programmers have a few very bad habits. Such as NOT using relational models but ISAM tables. Or doing data processing and referential integrity checks in application code instead of thinking about the right queries. Doing thousands of queries in a loop is almost always wrong. SQL is a very powerful language once you understand it. In SQL a JOIN is  often the replacement of a 'loop' or 'iteration over data'.

Comment: The UPDATE loop you do could maybe be replaced with the right JOIN statement so that it will result in one query.

I don't understand your code, so I could be wrong, but this is just my gut feeling as an experienced datamodeller and coder. :)